# S3 Methods: Extending ggplot2 `+.gg` function

Tags: r, ggplot2, methods, operator-overloading, ggproto

I am trying to extend `ggplot2` with a new class that we will call `foo` for this example. The goal is to write a `+.foo` method that will be used in place of `+.gg`. However I am running into an issue of "incompatible methods"

### The Setup

Currently I am able to write `ggplot_add.foo_layer` which will make `plot` into my `foo` class and then add the corresponding layer as normal.

The idea is that once the plot object inherits `foo` it will dispatch to `+.foo` when the next layer added.

The reason I would like to do this is because I want to check if the structure of `foo` object is still valid/compatible with the incoming layer. This will prevent me from having to write a method for `ggplot_build`.

### Code Definitions

```
library(ggplot2)

`+.foo` <- function(e1, e2){
  cat("Using foo ggplot +") # for Debugging
  NextMethod() #ideally just dispatches to `+.gg`
}

ggplot_add.foo_layer <- function(object, plot, object_name) {
  plot <- as_foo(plot)
  ggplot2:::add_ggplot(plot, object$layer, object_name) 
}

as_foo <- function(x){
  if(!is_foo(x)){
    class(x) <- c("foo", class(x))
  }
  x
}

is_foo <- function(x) inherits(x, "foo")

foo_layer <- function(x) structure(list(layer = x), class = "foo_layer")
```

### The Error

```
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()
class(p1)
#[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
p1 + geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(density)))


p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  foo_layer(geom_point()) 

class(p2)
#[1] "foo"    "gg"     "ggplot"
p2 + geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(density)))
#Error in p2 + geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(density))) : 
#  non-numeric argument to binary operator
#In addition: Warning message:
#Incompatible methods ("+.foo", "+.gg") for "+"
```

From the code above `p1 + geom_*` executes fine. However `p2 + geom_*` can not be made due to the above error about Incompatible methods. From what I know about S3 method dispatch I don't understand why this would not work. Could someone explain why this is or how I could remedy this.

Ideally I would not have to write a method `ggplot_build.foo` because I want other package's `ggplot_build` to be used if they exist (for example `gganimate`).

Comment: This will likely require changes on ggplot2's site as the Ops generics are notoriously bad for double dispatch under S3. Relevant discussion: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3818

Comment: @teunbrand Thank you! I've been trying to find some other discussions about this issue. I always assumed that the Ops generics only dispatched on the first argument.

Comment: Also, sometimes it might help if you let the ggplot developers know you'd like a feature. Probably https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3986 would be the appropriate place to rally support for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do is to overwrite ggplot2:::+gg method to support double dispatch in S3. This isn't really good behaviour if you're writing a package, but it gets the job done. Note that this being naughty behaviour hasn't stopped other packages from overwriting ggplot's functions (looking at you, ggtern).

```r
library(ggplot2)

`+.gg` <- function(e1, e2) {
  UseMethod("+.gg")
}

`+.gg.default` <- ggplot2:::`+.gg`

`+.gg.foo` <- function(e1, e2) {
  cat("Using foo ggplot +")
  NextMethod()
}

ggplot_add.foo_layer <- function(object, plot, object_name) {
  plot <- as_foo(plot)
  ggplot2:::add_ggplot(plot, object$layer, object_name) 
}

as_foo <- function(x){
  if(!is_foo(x)){
    class(x) <- c("foo", class(x))
  }
  x
}

is_foo <- function(x) inherits(x, "foo")

foo_layer <- function(x) structure(list(layer = x), class = "foo_layer")

p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()

p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  foo_layer(geom_point()) 


p2 + geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(density)))
#> Using foo ggplot +
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: For my own knowledge, would that mean my hypothetical package would need to be loaded after `ggplot2`, otherwise it would break?

Comment: I'd guess so otherwise the `+.gg` method that is a generic in your package would because non-generic due to ggplot2 overwriting the generic. But I haven't tested this.

Comment: I suppose wrapping my new `foo` object as an S4 might be the safest route. Thank you so much for the resources!

Comment: *new question gets posted* S4 methods extending ggplot2 `+.gg` function! ;p

Comment: No kidding, inheriting `c("gg","ggplot")` into S4 isnt exactly trivial, maybe there will be a new SO question haha

Answer (score 2):

Thanks the [resource provided by @teunbrand](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3818), we can use S4 to safely dispatch with `+`

## EDIT ----

It seems that between sessions this code is not actually dispatching on my defined S4 method `+`. For some reason its still dispatching to `+.gg`. I will do some research on dispatching on why this is, but for the time being, the below code does not work.

### S4 class Definitions

```
setOldClass(c("gg", "ggplot")) #required to make it inherit from gg
setClass("Foo", contains = c("gg","ggplot", "list"))
setMethod("initialize", "Foo",
          function(.Object, plot){
            .Object[names(plot)] <- plot
            .Object 
          } )


setMethod("+", signature(e1 = "Foo",e2 = "gg"),
          function(e1, e2){
            cat("Using S4 Method")
            gg <- ggplot2:::`+.gg`(e1, e2)
            as_foo(gg) #ensure that new layers (from other packages) dont return S3
          })
setMethod("show", signature("Foo"),
          function(object){
          ggplot2:::print.ggplot(object)})

ggplot_add.foo_layer <- function(object, plot, object_name) {
  plot <- as_foo(plot)
  ggplot2:::add_ggplot(plot, object$layer, object_name)
}

as_foo <- function(x){
  if(!is_foo(x)){
    x <- new("Foo", x)
  }
  x
}

is_foo <- function(x) inherits(x, "Foo")

foo_layer <- function(x) structure(list(layer = x), class = "foo_layer")
```

For all intents and purposes, the new `foo` object 'behaves' like a standard `ggplot` object.

```
p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  foo_layer(geom_point())
p2 + geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(density)))
```

Additionally, Other packages like `gganimate` will still return a `Foo` object but call their own `ggplot_build` S3 method

```
library(gganimate)
anim <- p2 + transition_states(Species)
is_foo(anim)
inherits(anim, "gganim")
anim
```