# How to add a warning when ggplot object is modified?

Tags: r, ggplot2, warnings

I have a function that modifies ggplot objects:

```
p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg)) + geom_point()

mod_gg <- function(plot) {
  plot$labels$x = "CYL"
  return(plot)
}

pnew = mod_gg(p)
```

However, some of the tinkering abouts that the function does IRL are pretty fragile. How could I set an alarm in `pnew` such that if someone tries to add a `scale_x_*` like:

```
> pnew = pnew + scale_x_discrete(limits = c(5,7)) # This shouldn't happen
```

An error, warning or message pops up to warn the user against the action. It could just be like when you try to add two scale_x_* to a single plot:

```
# Example
> pnew + scale_x_discrete(limits = c(5,7)) + scale_x_discrete(limits = c(5,7))
Scale for x is already present.
Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think one option would be to change the class of your returned object. This would require that you would create your own printing method too. I am here simply copying the print.ggplot method, and the necessary functions for it in a quick hack.

It should now (in my expectations) not be possible any more to add another ggplot layer. However, when trying this, adding some layers doesn't produce an error or warning, but just "NULL". But maybe it's already a start.

The lack of a warning/error is possibly due to the double dispatch of ggplot's `+.gg` method. Therefore, one solution to that problem might be to create your own `+.gg` method, like the {GGally} or {patchwork} packages do. But this comes at a cost: e.g., the GGally method has (or at least: used to have) some rather pesky interference with ggplot2's very own method, and I assume that the patchwork package has some really clever ways to avoid this interference which would probably be beyond the scope of this answer - but maybe worth a look into their source code if you want to walk that route.

Here an SO thread that discusses creation of custom `+.gg` methods. [S3 Methods: Extending ggplot2 `+.gg` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65817557/s3-methods-extending-ggplot2-gg-function)

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()

## this is just a quick hack for reprex purpose 
## would need some more in detail work when building your package
print.myplot <- ggplot2:::print.ggplot
ggplot_build.myplot <- ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot
get_alt_text.myplot <- ggplot2:::get_alt_text.ggplot

mod_gg <- function(plot) {
  plot$labels$x <- "CYL"
  class(plot) <- "myplot"
  plot
}
pnew <- mod_gg(p)
## The object can be printed with your new printing method
pnew
```

[image]

```r
## but other ggplot layers should (in theory) not be addable. 
pnew + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(5, 7))
#> NULL
pnew + geom_smooth()
#> NULL
pnew + labs()
#> Error in pnew + labs(): non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: (probably related GitHub thread https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3818)